# Controlling a button with a database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I have a project with Android studio. I want to do something using Java.

I created a data using the Firebase database. For example, let it be.
"buttoncolor" - "true"
I created a child here. I added the value "true" as the data. What I want to do is make a request for this data from the database. So get a button. If this data is "true", the button is not active. If I change this value to "false" I want the button to be active. I want to check the button in real time with the database. Is this possible?

How can I do if it is possible?

Comment: Yup, sounds totally possible. Did you try anything already? To learn how to create a button and enable/disable it, I recommend searching for an Android tutorial. To learn how to read from Firebase, I recommend reading the [Android documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write), and taking the [Android codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/). If you're having trouble making it work, share what you've tried already. In that case read [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: yes you can enable and disable button using firebase all you have to do is get button id and then check if data is true or false..

Answer (score 1):

Guessing that you are already fetching the database value of "buttoncolor".So to change the button as active or de-active just code like this,

for true value code,

```
mButton.setEnabled(false);
```

and for false value code,

```
mButton.setEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("buttons");
ref.orderByChild("bottonId").equalTo("true").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
      if(dataSnapshot.exist() {
       Boolean isEnable= (Boolean) dataSnapshot.getValue();

         if(isEnable){
      mButton.setEnabled(true);
       }else{
        mButton.setEnabled(false);
         }

          }
        }
```